# Java: Atore values of dynamically generated textboxes into database using hashset

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7, hashset

I have dynamically created textBoxes, number of input is given by the user.
These textBoxes contain the name and contact number of the user. Now I want to store these names and contact numbers into databases. Can anybody please tell me how to save data into database from dynamically generated textBoxes?

Comment: no different from textboxes that are not dynamically generated, whatever that means.

Comment: This question is a candidate for closure because it is hard to know what you are asking.  Please edit your post to provide more details.  Maybe a _small_ code sample?  What do you mean by "Textboxes"?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generated TextBoxes?? Well I'll just assume you are taking about JTextField or JTextArea.

First you must retrieve the values.

And secondly store them into a database table using JDBC or an ORM.

Without a clear question this is all i can offer.